In javascript, can I assign iframe doc to document variable?
I have a JavaScript code that works inside Iframe. I'd like to save the Iframe context so that my next script can work in the same context.
The following is my code
// Get the iframe element
const iframe = document.evaluate("/html[1]/body[1]/iframe[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 

// Access the iframe's document object
const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

// use iframe doc directly
var e1 = iframeDoc.evaluate("id('shadow_host')", iframeDoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(`e1=${e1}`);

// can I assign iframeDoc to document?
document = iframeDoc;
var e2 = document.evaluate("id('shadow_host')", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(`e2=${e2}`);

I got the following result
e1=[object HTMLDivElement]
e2=null

Looks like if I use Iframe doc directly, I able able to search inside the Iframe context. I did  this with e1.
But If I assign the Iframe doc to 'document" variable, I am not able to search inside the Iframe context. I did this with e2.
Why my e2 example doesn't work?
I really wanted to use 'document' variable because it is global and I don't have to pass a variable to my next call.
Thank you for any help

The global Window.Document is read-only so you can't reassign it.

Thank you. This can explain what I see. Is there any API that can set window.document to iframeDoc?

The issue with your e2 example is that reassigning document in the global scope does not change the actual document object that the browser provides—it only creates a local variable document that shadows the global document object. This local variable does not impact the context of subsequent JavaScript calls or the global document object.
Solution
Instead of trying to replace document, you can encapsulate your operations in a function or a closure that uses iframeDoc directly. Here’s how you can organize your code:
// Get the iframe element
const iframe = document.evaluate("/html[1]/body[1]/iframe[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

// Access the iframe's document object
const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

// Use iframeDoc directly
const e1 = iframeDoc.evaluate("id('shadow_host')", iframeDoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(`e1=${e1}`);

// Encapsulate iframe context operations
function withIframeContext(callback) {
  return callback(iframeDoc);
}

// Perform evaluation in iframe context
withIframeContext((doc) => {
  const e2 = doc.evaluate("id('shadow_host')", doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  console.log(`e2=${e2}`);
});


Thank you. Using a function with a callback is a new Idea. With callback function, it is a little hard to read but I will test it out. I also found a monkey patching way to make an global window.iframeDoc variable. I will post my way to let you and other people to comment.

From help from other Stackoverflow people, I know that window.document is readonly. Therefore, I gave up on overwriting it.
I found a monkey-patching way: make a global variable: window.iframeDoc.
// Get the iframe element
var iframe = document.evaluate("/html[1]/body[1]/iframe[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 

// Access the iframe's document object
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

// make iframeDoc global
window.iframeDoc = iframeDoc;

// later when other scripts not sure whether to use document or iframeDoc
var startDoc = document;
if (window.iframeDoc) {
    startDoc = window.iframeDoc;
}

var e2 = startDoc.evaluate("id('shadow_host')", startDoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(`e2=${e2}`);

The result
e2=[object HTMLDivElement]

It works for the purpose. Welcome to point out any drawback with it. Thank you
